# Overlapping letters in 3D Text in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Why does my threejs 3d textgeometry have overlapping letters when viewed at an angle?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
class MyScene {
    scene: THREE.Scene
    camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera
    renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer
    group: THREE.Group
    elementSelector: string
    cameraTarget: THREE.Vector3

    constructor(elementSelector: string) {
        this.elementSelector = elementSelector

        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(15, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, -1, 1500);


        scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
        // scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0xffffff, 250, 1400);

        camera.position.set(0, 400, 3000);

        this.cameraTarget = new THREE.Vector3(0, 150, 0);

        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.2);
        dirLight.position.set(0, 0, 1).normalize();
        scene.add(dirLight);

        const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1.5);
        pointLight.position.set(0, 400, 100);
        scene.add(pointLight);


        this.scene = scene
        this.camera = camera
        this.renderer = renderer

        const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => this._onResize());
        let containerElement = document.querySelector(elementSelector)
        if (!containerElement) {
            containerElement = document.body
        }
        resizeObserver.observe(containerElement, { box: 'content-box' });

        const group = new THREE.Group();
        // group.position.y = 100;
        scene.add(group);
        this.group = group

        var loader = new FontLoader()
        loader.load('assets/fonts/sourcecodepro_bold.typeface.json', font => {
            const textGeo = new TextGeometry("MyText", {
                font: font,
                size: 200,
                height: 50,
                curveSegments: 12,
                bevelEnabled: false,
                bevelThickness: 0.5,
                bevelSize: 0.3,
                bevelOffset: 0,
                bevelSegments: 5,
            })

            // const materials = [
            //     new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 }), // front
            //     new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 }) // side
            // ]
            const materials = [
                new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00, flatShading: true }), // front
                new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 }) // side
            ]
            const textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo, materials);

            textGeo.computeBoundingBox();
            const centerOffset = - 0.5 * (textGeo.boundingBox.max.x - textGeo.boundingBox.min.x);

            textMesh.position.x = centerOffset;
            textMesh.position.y = 30;
            textMesh.position.z = 0;

            textMesh.rotation.x = 0;
            textMesh.rotation.y = Math.PI * 2;

            group.add(textMesh);
        })


        // container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    }

    _onResize() {
        const container = document.querySelector(this.elementSelector);
        const width = container ? container.clientWidth : 100;
        const height = container ? container.clientHeight : 100;

        this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }

    onCreated() {
        this.mounted = true
        const root = this
        const animate = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate)
            root.group.rotation.y += 0.02;
            root.camera.lookAt(root.cameraTarget);
            root.renderer.render(root.scene, root.camera)
        }
        animate()
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s really strange. It looks like the text faces are being rendered back-to-front. What does your camera creation look like? It’s almost as if the frustum is inverted inside-out. Can you create a working demo on https://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @Marquizzo Added camera logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your camera creation is kind of a mess. You initialize it as a [PerspectiveCamera](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera) , and then you're replacing its properties with those of an [OrthographicCamera](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/OrthographicCamera). You have to pick one and stick to it. For example, `left, right, top, bottom` are not recognized by a `PerspectiveCamera`.

But I think the thing that's hurting your rendering the most is having a negative `.near` property. Try setting it to a small positive value, like `camera.near = 10;`

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I updated the code to remove that.  It only works if near is set to -1.  Do I have to move scene objects?  I posted the full ts code.

Comment: If it only works when you have `near = -1`, then there's something wrong with your setup, and your text is probably not properly positioned in front of the camera. [Your camera frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum) should not have a negative `near` value, because that would mean the near plane is inverted behind the camera, and that's why you're getting a rendering order that doesn't make much sense.